# ORBInitialHost parameter

Tags: java, corba, boost-program-options

Assume I have a java server which uses corba. When I start it with command

```
java server -ORBInitialHost localhost -ORBInitialPort 1111
```

I pass parametres `-ORBInitialHost localhost -ORBInitialPort 1111`. 
Will I have 2 elements of array `String [] args` (

```
args[0] -ORBInitialHost localhost,
args[1] -ORBInitialPort 1111
```

) or

4 elements(

```
args[0] -ORBInitialHost, 
args[1] localhost, 
args[2] -ORBInitialPort, 
args[3] 1111
```

)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be four parameters, as you put in the second code. The ORB code is written so that it takes into account the next array element as the parameter of the option.